# Advice re controls for keyboard app for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I am looking to develop a keyboard app for WP7. My son has done a pretty good one for ios and I would like to do the same under wp7.  I have a programming background but not in c# /Silverlight so seeing this as a chance to learn with a decent sort of project.

What I a struggling with is what controls I should use for this -even for starters i.e Stack Panel, Grid etc or whether I should be building a custom control. I haven't been near expression blend at all.

Really struggling with getting my head around the controls that I should be building this sort of thing with.

any advice appreciated.

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general answer to this, I'd say that this sounds like a great first project - you'll soon get the hang of Silverlight and master these initial problems - just get in there and start coding.

To work out how these different containers work:

- I like this set of simple explanations - http://wpf.nickthuesen.com/?page_id=33
- try working through some sample apps - e.g. take a look at a blog like http://sigurdsnorteland.wordpress.com/ - his projects use Grids, Canvases, etc and are often all in one cs/xaml file - so easy to get to grips with.

---

By keyboard, do you mean "music" or "typing"?

---

Assuming "typing" then take a look at how this works - http://wpkeyboard.codeplex.com/

---

Assuming, music, then take a look at:

- a simple piano - http://script.iron7.com/#/Script/Detail?scriptId=91287aa96ca74892b96171313c9b5ea2&userLowerCaseName=stuart
- a simple xylophone - http://script.iron7.com/#/Script/Detail?scriptId=6db87d269f3e4f18834bcece0e13fb8d&userLowerCaseName=stuart

Both of these use a set of buttons within a StackPanel.

For more advanced layout - e.g. for a keyboard that includes those black notes as well as the white ones, then you can look at using a Grid or a Canvas

---

Sorry - just looked some more - the music samples above are in ruby and contain some animation for when each key is pressed, so they might not be that easy for you to follow - but the basic idea is that those apps use very simple layout like:

```
   <StackPanel>
        <Button />
        <Button />
        <Button />
        <Button />
        <Button />
        <Button />
   </StackPanel>
```

One thing to bear in mind is that you can design several sets of layout independently of your app logic - so you can start with something simple/ugly and then make it more advanced/beautiful by changing only the xaml.

Answer (score 1):

The display of the SIP is handled by the operating system and will always be on top of the visual tree of any application. If you want to provide a custom SIP, you will need to provide an alternative input control, because the display of the native SIP is tied to input controls (such as `TextBox`, `PasswordBox`, etc.). You may find this article about [creating a Bulgarian keyboard](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx) useful.

In terms of actually layout out the keyboard, I'd probably go for a Grid-based layout, which gives you the flexibility to span multiple columns to make individual keys larger.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry I didn't explain myself well enough, its a music style keyboard I'm kooking to make - a Piano style.